# Storing part of an "import" statement in an array

Tags: python, module

This may be a slightly dumb question, but I want to know how to store the subclass of the exceptions class. Let me explain: I want to have an array like this:

```
excep_type = [ValueError, NameError, IoError, ...]
```

The reason why is I'm building a class that I'm going to which I'm going to be referring to these exceptions often. I know all these exceptions live in the exceptions module (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iNeb.jpg)), so how could I go about doing this?

EDIT: I'm sorry, I should've mention I want ALL the exceptions in an array. I could type them all out manually, but surely there must be a way to grab them all?

Comment: All those exceptions are built-ins; you don't need to import them, just use them.

Comment: You're not going to find a list of *every* exception. Even if you use something like starting at `BaseException` and traversing the `__subclasses__` tree, anyone can at any point create a new exception type. Why do you need a giant list of every single exception? Even if you're going to refer to them often, just do it by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use introspection like this:

> import exceptions
>
> my_exceptions = [x for x in dir(exceptions) if not x.startswith('__')]
>
> print my_exeptions
>
> ['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError',
>   'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning',
>   'EOFError', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'FloatingPointError',
>   'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError',
>   'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError',
>   'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError',
>   'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError',
>   'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError',
>   'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError',
>   'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'TypeError',
>   'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError',
>   'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning',
>   'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError']